# have problem with axios on two sequential request

Tags: php, vue.js, axios

I Have problem when two sequential request send and the second request get error --> Error: "Network Error"
for example :

```
OPTION : /meal/get      200 success
GET: /meal/get    200 success
OPTION: /message/get  200 get
dont send GET :/message/get
```

and show error

I check the header response of OPTIONS :  the response part of first option is true but the second is wrong

I use php for my backend and All of the part work truly

global config file:

```
axios.defaults.headers.get['Accept'] = 'application/json'
axios.defaults.headers.common['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
```

this is my code

```
           axios({
                method: 'get',
                url: '/message/index',
                data: {},
                params: {
                    page: page
                }
            }).then(res => {
```

header of response:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials    true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers    Origin, Accept, Content-Type, …, X-GR-   Token, Accept-Language
Access-Control-Allow-Methods    GET,POST,OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin *
Access-Control-Expose-Headers   X-Access-Token, X-Refresh-Toke…nation-Total-Count, X-Payload
Connection  Keep-Alive 
Content-Length  0
Content-Type    text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date    Mon, 11 Mar 2019 16:00:22 GMT
Keep-Alive  timeout=5, max=100
Server  Apache/2.4.27 (Win64) PHP/7.1.9
Status  200 OK
X-Powered-By    PHP/7.1.9
```

each request in different component

```
        axios({
            method: 'get',
            url: '/meal/suggest',
            data: {},
            params: {}
        }).then( res => {
            console.log(res)
            // this.rightSideData = res.data
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
            console.log(err.response.data)
        })
```

header response of this request:

```
Connection  Keep-Alive
Content-Length  876
Content-Type    text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date    Mon, 11 Mar 2019 16:00:23 GMT
Keep-Alive  timeout=5, max=100
Server  Apache/2.4.27 (Win64) PHP/7.1.9
X-Powered-By    PHP/7.1.9
```

Comment: what are you actually asking?

Comment: How can I solve this? what is my problem ? I saw the same questions but didn't give me write information @treyBake

Comment: How are we meant to know without seeing the code triggering this? Unfortunately, SO aren't telepathic (though that would be cool)

Comment: @treyBake I edit my queuestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution 
I set header in my php phalcon and It's response to first request but if I send two request in the same time It's answer just one of them and second borken

I search alot and understand I put header in .htaccess too 
this is my code:

```
#Header set Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self';"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://localhost:8080"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Content-Type, Accept-Language, X-Access-Token, X-Client-Id, X-Secret-Id, X-GR-Token"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET,POST,OPTIONS"
Header always set Access-Control-Expose-Headers "X-Access-Token, X-Refresh-Token,X-Access-Token-Expire, X-Pagination-Current-Page, X-Pagination-Page-Count,X-Pagination-Per-Page, X-Pagination-Total-Count, X-Payload"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true"
```